# ¿Cómo reorganizar la base de datos en Genexus? - Error al ejecutar

Tags: genexus

Estoy empezando a usar genexus, en principio entré por curiosidad, por la fama que está teniendo esa tecnología y luego muy interesado por lo rápido que podemos crear elementos me puse a seguir el curso gratuito que se ofrece en su página. El problema es que me tranqué en un ejercicio que al compilar y ejecutar la solución el sistema pide reorganizar la base de datos, esta vez, muestra 2 warnings, le doy "Reorganizar" pero esta vez, se produce un error y no puedo ejecutar. Peor aún, he hecho rollback a un punto anterior del programa y, como la base de datos ya fue reorganizada en otro estado, ya no sólo volví hacia atrás, sino que no puedo más compilar la solución.
El problema debe tener una solución super sencilla, lo sé, pero es que recién estoy comenzando con este "lenguaje" y al googlear el problema, lo que encuentro es info muy vaga, no mucho más de lo que ya arroja el sistema:

> Unexpected errors may occur if you don't try to finalize previous reorganization before running this one
> If you want to run this reorganization anyway, use '-ignoreresume' parameter in the Reorganization Options property of the generator
> The reorganization process was not successfully completed.
> Failed: Reorganization
> error: Error in reorganization
> Failed: Run Developer Menu

Obviamente la solución podría ser utilizar el parámetro -ignoreresume, pero ¿Dónde? ¿Por donde encuentro las opciones del generador, para reorganizar? Cabe señalar que hace un par de días empecé con esto y hasta el momento parecía todo muy fácil, pero la verdad al encontrar un error no resulta muy intuitivo saber por dónde va la solución, no queda claro si es un archivo de configuración, una opción de menú, en fin..

Muchas gracias desde ya :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victor, en las Preferences dentro del generador tenes una propiedad que se llama Reorganization Options  ahí agregale a lo que tenes -ignoreresume

Como llegas a las preferences : View - Preferences
En Preferences : Tenes el nombre de la KB - la versión (hijo) - Environment- y dentro de Backend tenes el generador

Answer (score -1):

gracias Álvaro. Hice lo que comentas y quedó funcionando. Excepto que no encontré la opción dentro del menú View pero sí en el lateral izquierdo, **el KB Explorer, metiéndome por ahí está enseguida el ".NET Environment", luego Backend, luego Default (C#) y ahí está todo**, donde se puede modificar las opciones de reorganización. Cabe señalar que uso la versión gratuita y por eso sólo puedo compilar para C# y mandar a la nube, de ahí que puede variar alguna opción. Estoy trabajando en este momento con GX17.
En resumidas cuentas, pese a que obviamente un poquito me va a costar adaptarme 100% al entorno y sus funcionalidades, es muchísimo más fácil y rápido construir algo en GX que en cualquier lenguaje de programación que antes haya visto, así que continuaré con los tutoriales y posiblemente vuelva a recurrir a esta comunidad :) un saludo!